# How to retrieve a VB Control instance, given its Name and Index?

Tags: arrays, string, vb6

If I have a string "cboEnoughMoney(0)", is it possible to retrieve the control from a control array that I have in my form, `cboEnoughMoney`?

In my code, I try to refer to the control in this way:

```
frm.Controls(sControlName).ListIndex = -1
```

`sControlName` in this case is "cboEnoughMoney(0)" and I get an error that the control was not found.

EDIT: One of the issue's i'm having is trying to as above set the .listindex to -1, another one is where I actually try to get and set value to the combobox. In a function - i pass form name as parameter called frm.

In the code what has been done is this....

```
dim ctlData as string
If Frm.Controls(RS!CTRLname).ListIndex > 0 Then
      CtlData = Frm.Controls(RS!CTRLname).Value
Else
      CtlData = ""
End If
```

Any idea how I'd be able to do that with cboEnoughMoney(0)....

I assume I could follow your example and check

```
if instr(1,RS!CTRLname, "(")
```

but if there is, how would I refer to that particular control in frm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `(index)` part in a lookup via `.Controls`.

You can loop them manually & given that you can safely assume any control name with a `(` is an array member and thus will have an `Index` property match on that:

```
Private Function GetControl(ByVal name As String) As VB.Control
    Dim pos As Long: pos = InStr(name, "(")

    If pos = 0 Then
        Set GetControl = Me.Controls(name) '// non array
    Else
        Dim index As Long
        index = Val(Mid$(name, pos + 1))   '// get index #
        name = Left$(name, pos - 1)        '// get base name

        For Each GetControl In Me.Controls
           If (GetControl.name = name) Then
                If (GetControl.index = index) Then Exit Function
            End If
        Next

        Set GetControl = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

And then:

```
GetControl("cboEnoughMoney(1)").ListIndex = -1
```

Comment: You would `GetControl(RS!CTRLname).ListIndex = -1`

Comment: this if statement.....If Frm.Controls(RS!CTRLname).ListIndex > 0 Then does not recognize the control at all - so it basically throw an error as per your earlier comment that I cannot use indexed controls with frm.controls - but how is it that I can do frm.CboEnoughMoney(0)?? Thank you again.

Comment: `frm.CboEnoughMoney(0)` is handled at compile time, its entirely different from looking up a control at runtime from a string.  The `.controls(x)` collection looks up a control by name, and even though `CboEnoughMoney` is in an array `CboEnoughMoney(0).Name` is just `"CboEnoughMoney"`

Answer (score 3):

It is just enough to look in the VB Properties Window: if you search "cboEnoughMoney(0)" you will find "cboEnoughMoney"(0) (without double quotes). Still the name is the same as a non-array control.

[image: Properties Window]

So, it is perfectly legal to refer to a VB Control with Name and Index, no need for a controls loop here:

```
If isControlsArray Then
    Set ctrl = Me.Controls(Name)(Index) '// array
Else
    Set ctrl = Me.Controls(Name) '// non array
End If
```